# JTree not displaying added nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I'm trying to create my first `JTree`, but when I try to add my nodes to the tree, the changes aren't taking effect and all that's displayed is a tree with some default nodes in it (colors, sports, food).

My main panel code in which the tree resides:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
public class Scenario1Panel extends JPanel
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Scenario1Tree scenario1Tree;

public Scenario1Panel()
{
    scenario1Tree = new Scenario1Tree();
    add(scenario1Tree);
}
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    try
    {
        String lookAndFeel = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        System.out.println(lookAndFeel);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("couldn't get that LookAndFeel");
    }

    Scenario1Panel mgr = new Scenario1Panel();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.add(mgr);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

My tree code is:

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;
public class Scenario1Tree extends JTree
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JTree tree;

public Scenario1Tree()
{
    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Scenario1");
    createNodes(top);
    tree = new JTree(top);

    //Create a tree that allows one selection at a time.
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode
        (TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);

    //Create the scroll pane and add the tree to it. 
    JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);


}

private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode loginUser1 = null;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode addNewUsers = null;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode addNewUsersBreakout = null;

    loginUser1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Login User 1");
    top.add(logintUser1);

    addNewUsers = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Add New Users");
    top.add(addNewUsers);

    addNewUsersBreakout = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Add User2");
    addNewUsers.add(addNewUsersBreakout );
    addNewUsersBreakout = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Add User3");
    addNewUsers.add(addNewUsersBreakout );
    addNewUsersBreakout = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Add User4");
    addNewUsers.add(addNewUsersBreakout );
    addNewUsersBreakout = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Add User5");
    addNewUsers.add(addNewUsersBreakout );

}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    try
    {
        String lookAndFeel = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        System.out.println(lookAndFeel);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("couldn't get that LookAndFeel");
    }

    Scenario1Tree tree = new Scenario1Tree();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.add(tree);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `public class Scenario1Tree extends JTree`  Don't extend tree unless adding new functionality or overriding old.  Don't extend `JPanel` either, just keep an instance.

Comment: Look first for JTree demo/examples. [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEr4XVMVdRE) or others. The [NetBeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org) has a nice GUI editor. Inspect the code. Maybe you are already using NetBeans, because it uses a dummy TreeModel as JTree constructor args, but one can also call the constructor with a root node. The code now has to be changed much.

Comment: Problem is I've never used Java, so this is all new to me. I've been trying to follow this example: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

Don't I need to use extends in order to use methods in the class like add?  If I remove "extends tree" then add(Scenario1Tree) no longer works.

Answer (score 6):

You're creating one JTree too many. You're adding all your nodes to a JTree variable and yet using a JTree extended class for the displayed tree, the latter of which has had no nodes added to it.

I suggest that you do not have your class extend JTree, that you instead give it a method, say `getTree()` that returns the JTree when and where needed.

i.e.,

```
// get rid of extends JTree
public class Scenario1Tree // extends JTree
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JTree tree;

public Scenario1Tree()
{
    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Scenario1");
    createNodes(top);
    tree = new JTree(top);

    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode
        (TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);

    // JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);

}

public JTree getTree() {
  return tree;
}
```

Comment: +1 I think your approach is even better but would require a bit more changes in original code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm having a really hard time figuring out the difference between what I wrote and the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).  I'm creating all my nodes in the variable top and then defining `tree = new Jtree(top)` like the example. Obviously, I'm missing something obvious in my understanding.

Comment: @Matt: get rid of the `extends JTree` from your code. Start from there.

Answer (score 5):

In the `Scenario1Tree` instead of `JTree` instance creating call

```
setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(top));
```

In fact you don't need the `JTree` instance at all.

Comment: My answer goes the other route -- that he shouldn't have his class extend JTree, but this will work as well (though I prefer avoiding inheritance where it's not needed). 1+